# How to set up Chern-Simons theory, compute its "topological gauge shift" term, and compute its quantum path integrals with Wilson lines?

Tags: mathematical-physics, knot-theory, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

Suppose we want to consider Chern-Simons theory on an (odd-dimensional) compact boundaryless smooth manifold $X$ for a Lie group (the "structure/gauge group") $G$.

Is it possible to do so without using a principal bundle on $M$ with connection? (Or perhaps this essentially uses the trivial principal bundle?)

As follows:

We take our "gauge field", labeled $A$, to be a section of $\Omega^1(X,\frak{g})$.

We define a "gauge transformation" by $g : X\rightarrow G$ on $A$
to be given by
$A \mapsto \mathrm{Ad}_g A + (g^{-1})^*\theta$ where $\theta$ is the Maurer-Cartan form on $G$ (and $g^{-1}$ means pointwise $G$-inversion of $g$), following the formula [at this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory_(mathematics)#Connections_on_principal_bundles). (For matrix groups this is $A \mapsto gAg^{-1} + g^{-1}dg$.)

We take as our field Lagrangian $k \omega_A$ where $\omega_A$ is the Chern-Simons form (as defined [at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Simons_form)) for $A$, and the action $S$ is the integral over $X$ of the Lagrangian density. Here $k$ is a (real) constant.

We verify that although the Chern-Simons form isn't invariant under gauge transformations of $A$, it changes by a total derivative at least when the gauge transformation is connected to the identity (a "small" gauge transformation), so that the value of the Chern-Simons action integral $S$ over $X$ (which is boundaryless) is unchanged by such a gauge transformation.

So now we can consider the classical dynamics of $A$ on $X$ without reference to any principal bundle on $X$? Or, is this essentially just the case of using the trivial principal bundle $X\times G \xrightarrow{\mathrm{proj}_1} X$? Is there a way to extend the above to nontrivial principal bundles?

---

Now, if we consider the quantum action $\mathrm{exp}(\frac{i}{\hbar}S)$, we can verify that even if we now allow gauge transformations not connected to identity, the classical action $S$ shifts by an overall constant times some "winding number" (as stated on p. 354 in [Witten's paper on QFT and the Jones polynomial](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/beem/papers/jones_polynomial_witten.pdf)),
such that the *quantum action* is unchanged if the constant $k$ in our theory is appropriately quantized.

With the choice of $k$ made, if we want to consider the quantum path integral for our theory, would its space of field configurations $\mathcal{M}$ be the space of sections $\Omega^1(X,\frak{g})$, quotiented by gauge transformations (both large or small, i.e. whether or not connected to identity)?

Also, does anyone have a reference explaining (or can explain) how to show how $S$ changes under a "large" gauge transformation (not connected to identity) by an overall topological term? (And is this only for 3-manifolds, which is the only case considered in Witten's paper unless I've missed something.)

Finally, should we expect that the quantum path integral - i.e. the integral of the quantum action $\exp(iS[A]/\hbar)$ over the space $\mathcal{M}$ of field configurations (on $X$), for some appropriate measure on $\mathcal{M}$, which may depend on choices of metrics on $\frak{g}$, $G$, $X$, etc - should be a topological invariant of $X$?

More generally, should the path integral (over $\mathcal{M}$)
of $\exp(iS[A]/\hbar)\,W(\gamma_1,\rho_1,A)\cdots W(\gamma_k,\rho_k,A)$
be an isotopy invariant of links $\gamma : (S^1)^{\sqcup k} \hookrightarrow X$?
Here $\gamma : (S^1)^{\sqcup k} \hookrightarrow X$ is an embedded link in $X$ with assigned $G$-representations $\rho_i$ to each link component, and $W(\gamma_i,\rho_i,A)$ is the [Wilson loop](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Wilson+loop#idea) (i.e. holonomy for the associated principal bundle connection?) of $A$ around $\gamma_i$, traced over $\rho_i$. (To use Wilson lines, do we need to assume $G$ is a matrix group?)